# Combine rows and sum N for DF in R

Tags: r

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(
N = c(20,10,5,5,3),
Product1 = c('Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear')[c(1,2,1,3,3)],
Product2 = c('Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear')[c(2,1,3,1,4)]
)
```

I would like to combines rows that are the same and sum the N  values even if the values in the the product column's are the wrong way round.

i.e.

```
20  Orange  Apple   HU16 
10  Apple   Orange  HU16
```

could be

```
30  Orange  Apple   HU16
```

Any ideas?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, daffer! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block]. (Your second block is a small example, but it seems you'd prefer we use your image for sample data when walking through code.)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  N = c(20, 10, 5, 5, 3),
  Product1 = c("Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Banana"),
  Product2 = c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Pear"),
  Store = c("HU16", "HU16", "HU16", "HU16", "HU16")
)

# Create a new column with sorted product names
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Product_Sorted = paste(sort(c(Product1, Product2)), collapse = ""))

# Summarize the data by grouping on the sorted product names
result <- data %>%
  group_by(Store, Product_Sorted) %>%
  summarise(Total_N = sum(N))


print(result)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Store [1]
  Store Product_Sorted Total_N
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
1 HU16  AppleOrange         30
2 HU16  BananaOrange        10
3 HU16  BananaPear           3
```

Comment: Hi with the results DF the column Product_Sorted is now a dataframe.  How do I convert results DF to a normal df with normal columns

Comment: How do you differentiate between "dataframe" and "normal df with normal columns"?

Comment: How do I turn dbl into a normal column?

Comment: `dbl` means numeric, it is a normal column

Answer (score 2):

Sort the `Product*` columns before doing a "normal" summarize.

If you are okay with changing the order "permanently", then you can do:

```r
data %>%
  mutate(setNames(data.frame(t(apply(pick(Product1, Product2), 1, sort))), c("Product1", "Product2"))) %>%
  summarize(N = sum(N), .by = c("Product1", "Product2", "Store"))
#   Product1 Product2 Store  N
# 1    Apple   Orange  HU16 30
# 2   Banana   Orange  HU16 10
# 3   Banana     Pear  HU16  3
```

If you'd prefer to not keep the sorted pairs, then we can (temporarily) create a new column with the products in a sorted view, then group on that. In order for this to reduce the number of rows, however, we need to arbitrarily choose which among the multiple mostly-matching products we select; I'll use the `first` values for each.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(products = apply(pick(Product1, Product2), 1, function(z) toString(sort(z)))) %>%
  summarize(
    N = sum(N),
    across(c(Product1, Product2), ~ first(.)), .by = c(products, Store)
  ) %>%
  select(-products)
#   Store  N Product1 Product2
# 1  HU16 30   Orange    Apple
# 2  HU16 10   Orange   Banana
# 3  HU16  3   Banana     Pear
```

(The only difference between this and Umar's answer is that this *adds* the combined column instead of replacing the original product columns.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(igraph)
data %>%
    relocate(N, .after = Store) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    summarise(N = sum(N), .by = c(from, to, Store)) %>%
    relocate(N, .before = from) %>%
    setNames(names(data))
```

or

```
data %>%
    relocate(N, .after = Store) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    simplify(edge.attr.comb = list(N = "sum", Store = "first")) %>%
    as_data_frame() %>%
    relocate(N, .before = from) %>%
    setNames(names(data))
```

which gives

```
   N Product1 Product2 Store
1 30   Orange    Apple  HU16
2 10   Orange   Banana  HU16
3  3   Banana     Pear  HU16
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1 (Base):

Similar idea to creating a new sorted column

```
df$Product <- with(df, 
  mapply(function(...) paste(sort(c(...)), collapse=', '),
  Product1,
  Product2
))

res <- aggregate(df[, 'N', drop=F], df[, 'Product', drop=F], sum)
```

gives

```
         Product  N
1  Apple, Orange 30
2 Banana, Orange 10
3   Banana, Pear  3
```

Notice, that although verbose, supplying the argument `collapse=', '` makes the result highly readable. If you need the result in a two-column format, you can either disaggregate the above result using code such as:

```
res[, c('Product1', 'Product2')] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(res$Product, ', '))
```

#### Option 2 (Base):

Rather than collapsing the column you can overwrite the original result with the sorted result according to

```
df[, c('Product1', 'Product2')] <- t(apply(df[, c('Product1', 'Product2')], 1, sort))
```

Then using the same `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(df[, 'N', drop=F], df[, c('Product1', 'Product2')], sum)

> aggregate(df[, 'N', drop=F], df[, c('Product1', 'Product2')], sum)
  Product1 Product2  N
1    Apple   Orange 30
2   Banana   Orange 10
3   Banana     Pear  3
```